# How would a better nihilist respond to pity from another?

Tags: nietzsche, nihilism

How would a good nihilist respond to pity from another, given that God is dead? Even if one approves of the motive and action, that's got to be quite the head-ache for any self respecting nihilist.

Comment: God lives and is the very source of life. According to [IEP](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nietzsch/), "Some interpreters of Nietzsche believe he [...] rejected philosophical reasoning, [...] while not being concerned with gaining truth and knowledge in the traditional sense of those terms." Therefore, his assertion that God is dead should not be taken as having any basis in fact, and there's also good reason to believe that he didn't actually believe it himself.

Comment: The idea of a "self respecting nihilist" is self-contradictory, because self respect is a value judgement. For the same reason, it doesn't make sense to think of Nietzsche as a nihilist because he was very vocal about making value judgements. Maintaining any sort of values is also logically inconsistent with atheism because of the [naturalistic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalistic_fallacy).

Comment: @PédeLeão ah whether or not we call Nietzsche a nihilist as he did is beside the point i hoped for my question

Comment: Understood. However, I believe the answer is very simple: a true nihilist would do his best to answer indifferently in order not to betray the fact that he actually makes value judgements—kind of the way a toaster would respond to having bread inserted in its slots. Any other reaction would be inconsistent with his claims.

Comment: @PédeLeão cheers for the Reply. i'm drunk

Comment: @PédeLeão Both of your assertions are pretty wide from the mark. Note "...not being concerned with gaining truth and knowledge _in the traditional sense of those terms_." You also give no interpretation of Nietzsche's claim nor any reason to think he did not believe it. Also, how atheism and the naturalistic fallacy have _anything_ to do with one another is beyond me. The naturalistic fallacy is as much of an issue for theists as atheists and doesn't preclude either from having values.

Comment: @Dennis. How does requoting to quote serve as an argument? I read it the first time. So how does Nietzsche gain knowledge? In his own words: "I have not come to know atheism as a result of logical reasoning and still less as an event in my life: in me *it is a matter of instinct*." Hardly any reason to doubt what God has made known, as a question of His justice, to mankind to the extent that we are all without excuse. Concerning the naturalistic fallacy, that's just a question of logic. I don't see that as questionable either.

Comment: @PédeLeão I requoted with emphasis to highlight the part you conveniently ignored. You might have read it, but you either missed the emphasized portion or conveniently ignored it in your critical comment. You made sweeping claims with no justification, the burden is on you to provide justification for your interpretation. You might think he's wrong, which is all well and good, but you have hardly provided any reason for others to agree. Without an interpretation of his claim, or discussion of his epistemology, your claim is unsubstantiated assertion (+armchair psychology regarding his beliefs)

Comment: @PédeLeão as for the naturalistic fallacy, I still haven't the slightest idea how that precludes atheists from having values. Not all atheists reduce intrinsic value, and even fewer argue for values in the "naturalistic" way the fallacy concerns. Note too that theists, such as Thomas Aquinas with his _Natural Law Theory of Morality_, seem just as susceptible to falling into the "naturalistic fallacy". But the claim that it's "just a matter of logic" suggests you don't appreciate the difference between formal and informal fallacies, and prefer "fallacy name dropping" to argumentation.

Comment: @Dennis. "The term 'naturalistic fallacy' is sometimes used to describe the deduction of an "ought" from an 'is' (the [is–ought problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is%E2%80%93ought_problem))." For example: **P** claims **Q**, therefore **P** *should* justify **Q**. The first is a statement of fact, and the second is a normative principle which doesn't follow from the premise. Hope that clears it up.

Comment: @PédeLeão I get it, but there's nothing that says that atheists must only accept facts and not values. That was my initial objection. Likewise, theists face the same problem with a religiously based morality. Why does the fact that God wills something entail that we ought to do it? This is just wholly independent of the question of theism/atheism.

Comment: @Dennis. The logical distinct nature of normative propositions is due to an independent standard which serves as a norm. God has the authority to legislate, so there is no further need to justify His precepts which by their very nature are normative. It's true that normative propositions can be expressed as facts, such as "God prohibits stealing." An atheist could ignore such assertions as meaningless, but the problem is that God created man with a rich sense of morality and related dispositions which very few are able to ignore.

Comment: @Dennis. How can the atheist account for a compelling sense that there is some objective standard of conduct, logically independent of any factual description of it? A sickening sense of dread sometimes accompanies a guilty conscience, but the same act under different subjective circumstances might be considered heroic. The difficulty is compounded when we consider that this applies not just to moral judgements but all subjective preferences. A instinctive drive to survive doesn't imply that survival is preferable to death.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your question makes any sense given the fact nihilists themselves rarely consider any outside emotional reactions to their beliefs from 3rd parties and even another nihilist can be considered a 3rd party. The idea behind [nihilism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nihilism) is that one can deny the value of virtually everything including thyself, therefore, prescribing any value to anything, including pity, doesn't "fly" well within nihilism.

In such circumstances one wouldn't bother too much to deny the intention behind everything (including pity) even from someone who could be considered a comrade. In the sense nihilism is used in philosophy today it makes it possible for a person to respond negatively to any emotion, even the ones who are positive when directed at him/her. This is why a "good nihilist" shouldn't have any problems denying the intentions of any other party including other nihilists and be able to live up to the promises of this worldview without any kind of "head-ache".

P.S. However, the question remains is such a worldview really something worth adhering to? I personally wouldn't advice for nihilism but it's probably the only philosophy able to deny everything thrown at its prescribers, so questions like yours user3293056 really don't make any sense to a "self respecting nihilist".